# Update a sliced rendered array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, push, splice

So I have two arrays. One filled with content and an empty one. What currently works is that using a onClick function, I splice the value from the first array and push it into the second array. 
This all works fine (tested using console.log). But the array that I render in my second class doesn't update

### What I currently have

```
export class OpeningHoursContent extends Component {

constructor (props) {
    super (props)
    this.state = {
        OpeningHoursUsed : [],
        OpeningHoursOptions : [
            {value: 'open247', option: 'Open 24/7', title: 'Open 24/7', content: 'We are open 24/7'},
            {value: 'openClosed', option: 'Open / Closed', title: 'Open / Closed', content: '<OpeningHoursTable />'},
            {value: 'holidays', option: 'Holidays', title: 'Holidays', content: '<ListHolidays />'},
            {value: 'showroom', option: 'Showroom', title: 'Showroom', content: '<OpeningHoursTable />'},
            {value: 'shop', option: 'Shop', title: 'Shop', content: '<OpeningHoursTable />'},
            {value: 'office', option: 'Office', title: 'Office', content: '<OpeningHoursTable />'},
            {value: 'deskoffice', option: 'Deskoffice', title: 'Deskoffice', content: '<OpeningHoursTable />'},
            {value: 'workspace', option: 'Workspace', title: 'Workspace', content: '<OpeningHoursTable />'},
            {value: 'vacation', option: 'Vacation', title: 'Vacation', content: '<ListVacation />'},
            {value: 'appointment', option: 'Appointment', title: 'Appointment', content: '<OpeningHoursTable />'},
            {value: 'selfservice', option: 'Selfservice', title: 'Selfservice', content: '<OpeningHoursTable />'},
            {value: 'addMessage', option: 'Add a message', title: 'Your message', content: '<OpeningHoursTable />'},
            {value: 'addCustom', option: 'Add custom', title: 'Custom title', content: '<OpeningHoursTable />'}
        ]
    }
}

UpdateOpeningHoursUsed ({ value, option, title, content }, index) {
    this.state.OpeningHoursUsed.push({ value: value, option: option, title: title, content: content })
    this.state.OpeningHoursOptions.splice(index, 1);
}

render () {
    return (
        this.state.OpeningHoursOptions.map(({ value, option, title, content }) => {
                return (
                    <div key={value} onClick={() => this.UpdateOpeningHoursUsed({ value, option, title, content })} className='option'>{option}</div>
                );
        })
    )
}
}

export default class EditOpeningHours extends Component  {
render () {

    return (
        <div>
            // THIS PART SHOULD RERENDER AFTER SPLICE
            <OpeningHoursContent />
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not mutate the state, instead use setState to update state. using setState will also trigger a re-render that allows you to see the updated data in render

```
UpdateOpeningHoursUsed ({ value, option, title, content }, index) {
    this.setState(state => {
       const updated = state.OpeningHoursUsed.concat([{ value: value, option: option, title: title, content: content }])
       return {
           OpeningHoursUsed: updated,
           OpeningHoursOptions: updated.splice(index, 1)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't has 2 way binding, so you need to update the two arrays using `setState`

```
UpdateOpeningHoursUsed ({ value, option, title, content }, index) {
    this.state.OpeningHoursUsed.push({ value: value, option: option, title: title, content: content })
    this.state.OpeningHoursOptions.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({OpeningHoursUsed, OpeningHoursOptions});
}
```

Comment: I have tried your way; but React tells me that 'OpeningHoursUsed' and 'OpeningHoursOptions' are not defined (On the line: this.setState...)